# Which ESBs implement EAI patterns directly?

Tags: design-patterns, esb, eai

I know that service-mix do it by using camel. Which other ESBs uses the EAI patterns as documented by Gregor Hohpe and Bobby Woolf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be very surprised to find many commercial ESBs explicitly to use the EAI Patterns book as their check-list as Camel have done [here](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) - and note that Camel does not implement all patterns there.

However, if you consider what any ESB needs to do it's almost inevitable that they will implement many of the patterns. Hence I'd predict that you'd be able to build a check-list with extensive coverage of the EAI patterns for any serious commercial ESB.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Camel, Apache Servicemix and Mule also support some of the widely used EIP patterns.